# Как правильно передать данные о кодировке в функции?

Tags: c++, winapi, кодировка, ascii, utf

В первый параметр CmdLine нижеприведенной функции передается терминальная команда. Результат выполнения записывается в параметр ListStdOut. Проблема заключается в том, что в ListStdOut записывается строка с иероглифами вместо ожидаемой строки. Как правильно передать данные о кодировке в эту функцию?

```
int SystemCapture(
    std::wstring CmdLine,
    std::wstring CmdRunDir,
    std::wstring& ListStdOut,
    std::wstring& ListStdErr, 
    uint32_t& RetCode)    
{
    int                  Success;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  security_attributes;
    HANDLE               stdout_rd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE               stdout_wr = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE               stderr_rd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE               stderr_wr = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  process_info;
    STARTUPINFOW         startup_info;
    std::thread          stdout_thread;
    std::thread          stderr_thread;

    security_attributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    security_attributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    security_attributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

    if (!CreatePipe(&stdout_rd, &stdout_wr, &security_attributes, 0) ||
        !SetHandleInformation(stdout_rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!CreatePipe(&stderr_rd, &stderr_wr, &security_attributes, 0) ||
        !SetHandleInformation(stderr_rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        if (stdout_rd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(stdout_rd);
        if (stdout_wr != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(stdout_wr);
        return -2;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&process_info, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));

    startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
    startup_info.hStdInput  = 0;
    startup_info.hStdOutput = stdout_wr;
    startup_info.hStdError  = stderr_wr;

    if (stdout_rd || stderr_rd)
        startup_info.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    _TCHAR CmdLineStr[MAX_PATH];
    wcsncpy(CmdLineStr, CmdLine.c_str(), MAX_PATH);
    CmdLineStr[MAX_PATH - 1] = 0;

    Success = CreateProcessW(
        nullptr,
        (LPWSTR)CmdLineStr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        TRUE,
        0,
        nullptr,
        CmdRunDir.c_str(),
        &startup_info,
        &process_info
    );
    CloseHandle(stdout_wr);
    CloseHandle(stderr_wr);

    if (!Success) {
        CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
        CloseHandle(stdout_rd);
        CloseHandle(stderr_rd);
        return -4;
    }
    else {
        CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
    }

    if (stdout_rd) {
        stdout_thread = std::thread([&]() {
            DWORD  n;
            const size_t bufsize = 1000;
            _TCHAR buffer[bufsize];
            for (;;) {
                n = 0;
                int Success = ReadFile(
                    stdout_rd,
                    buffer,
                    (DWORD)bufsize,
                    &n,
                    nullptr
                );
                
                if (!Success || n == 0)
                    break;
                std::wstring s(buffer, n);
                
                ListStdOut += s;
            }
        });
    }

    if (stderr_rd) {
        stderr_thread = std::thread([&]() {
            DWORD        n;
            const size_t bufsize = 1000;
            _TCHAR buffer[bufsize];
            for (;;) {
                n = 0;
                int Success = ReadFile(
                    stderr_rd,
                    buffer,
                    (DWORD)bufsize,
                    &n,
                    nullptr
                );
                
                if (!Success || n == 0)
                    break;
                std::wstring s(buffer, n);
                
                ListStdOut += s;
            }
        });
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if (!GetExitCodeProcess(process_info.hProcess, (DWORD*)&RetCode))
        RetCode = -1;

    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);

    if (stdout_thread.joinable())
        stdout_thread.join();

    if (stderr_thread.joinable())
        stderr_thread.join();

    CloseHandle(stdout_rd);
    CloseHandle(stderr_rd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос задан не правильно. Кирилица - это наше название русских символов. Её нельзя включить/выключить. Это более общее понятие. В программирование используется кодировка. Если два программы работают в одинаковых кодировках, и одинаково отображают данные - проблем вообще нет. Если какая-то из частей программы использует другую кодировку, а ещё хуже, если неправильно переводит её из непонятно-какой-кодировки в какую-то другую - то тут возникают проблемы.

Comment: Для разрешения проблемы нужно 1) точно знать в какой кодироке входящие данные. 2) точно знать кодировку того средства, через которое мы смотрим данные, например кодировку консоли. (это может быть кодировка файла, кодировка ACP-системы при выводе в окно. Как вариант "по глюкам" (визуальному виду текста) иногда можно угадать 1 и 2 по "скринам" (но не всегда). Проблема эта разрешается принудительным перекодированием. Так как в вашем вопросе ничего такого нету - то и ответить на вопрос - не возможно.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за ответ, предполагал что использование типов std::wstring, TCHAR и решит вопрос с кодировкой

Comment: Кодировка может содержать кирилицу, может не содержать. И даже две кодировки содержащие кирицицу - не совместимы между собой и требуют перевода. Поэтому тут важна кодировка, а не наличие кирилицы. Кирилицу поддерживает много кодировок, штук 10.

Comment: Не всегда. Если то куда идут данные не поддерживает юникод, что бывает часто - то отображение вполне может быть не верным. Для консоли такое часто встречается.

Comment: Кодировка вывода зависит исключительно от запускаемого приложения.

Comment: @user7860670 бывает кодировка в дебаггере,  в файле - эти кодировки не будут (или не всегда будут) зависеть от приложения.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну а вопрос-то про вывод, которое запускаемое приложение пишет в стандартные потоки.

Comment: Если это консоль - в консоли нужно переключить кодировку програмно.

Comment: @user7860670 стандартный - не равно консоль. Его можно перенаправить. Я тут не увидел обращение к стандартному, если написано имя переменной std это ещё ничего не значит. Не увидел стандартный ввод вывод в консоль.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я вроде нигде не упоминал консоль. B при чем тут std? Тут же речь не идет о потоках ввода-вывода из стандартной библиотеки С++, а о https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: ReadFile - у вас читает символы в той кодировке, с которой работает "перехваченая" программа. Обычно это будет.... или 1251 или 866. Вы не можете её тупо взять и в wstring упаковать. Вам её надо раскодировать и только тогда можно в wstring. Такие кодировки из std не совместимы с widestring. Ну разве что вы сможете обьяснить программе что ваша текущая кодировка std юникод, и согласится дать вам данные в юникоде. Я не пробовал переключать std на юникод, не уверен что это выйдет. Для перекодирования в юникод нужно использовать например multibytetowidechar, где первый аргумент - ваша кодировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadFile - у вас читает символы в той кодировке, с которой работает "перехваченая" программа. Обычно это будет.... или 1251 или 866. Вы не можете её тупо взять и в wstring упаковать. Вам её надо раскодировать и только тогда можно в wstring. Такие кодировки из std не совместимы с widestring. Ну разве что вы сможете обьяснить программе что ваша текущая кодировка std юникод, и согласится дать вам данные в юникоде. Я не пробовал переключать std на юникод, не уверен что это выйдет. Для перекодирования в юникод нужно использовать например [multibytetowidechar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar), где первый аргумент - ваша кодировка.

```
 const size_t bufsize = 1000;
        _TCHAR buffer[bufsize];
        wchar_t wbuffer[bufsize];
        for (;;) {
            n = 0;
            int Success = ReadFile(
                stderr_rd,
                buffer,
                (DWORD)bufsize,
                &n,
                nullptr
            );
            
            if (!Success || n == 0)
                break;
            n=MultiByteToWideChar(1251/*кодировка!!*/, 0, buffer, n,  wbuffer, n);
            std::wstring s(wbuffer, n);
```

Кодировку - подберёте.
Есть так же ф-ции стандрартной библиотеки для обработки, но я с ними не сталкивался. Ещё, не все дебагеры понимают wstring, если ваш не понимает - прийдётся перевести в string 1251.

Некоторые программы умеют выдавать информацию сразу в юникоде. Тогда ничего менять не нужно, надо просто запустить программу с такими параметрами, чтобы программа дала ответ в юникоде, для вашего случая вот так `cmd.exe /U /C dir` + кодировка CP_UNICODE

P.S. Кодировки бывают CP_ACP CP_UNICODE 1251 866 CP_UTF8. Разные программы могут выдавать информацию в разных кодировках. Обычно используется системная кодировка, но могут быть исключения.

Comment: Какие минусы? Спасибо за ответ, уже лучше. Выглядит примерно так https://pasteboard.co/K85eo3A.jpg

Comment: Кодировку 866 пробовали?

Comment: тот что выглядит ????.txt в https://pasteboard.co/K85eo3A.jpg это тест.txt

Comment: Команда dir если не правильно выставлено CP в консоли может давать сама вопросительные знаки. Тут важно, что бы когда в консоли запускаете команду dir, то она ?????? не выдавала. К сожелению можно один файл имя сделать в одной кодировке, а имя другой файла сделать в другой таким образом что dir даст вопросы.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K85jhHv.png здесь отображается корректно

Comment: Я тут подумал.... Вероятно в одной папке одна кодировка, а в другой другая, поэтому такой результат. А верните как было, и поменяйте commandline на `cmd /U /C dir` что бы переключить кодировку в юникод. Вдруг сработает. Юникод должен всё понимать.

Comment: Вернул, https://pasteboard.co/K85lJyA.jpg

Comment: Так у вас кодировка 1251, поменяйте wbuffer на buffer тут `std::wstring s(buffer, n);` а `MultiByteToWideChar`   закоментируйте (плюс ключ \U).

Comment: Есть ещё CP_UNICODE кодировка. Избыточно но тоже можно. (что бы не делать ветку на  `std::wstring s(buffer, n)` и `std::wstring s(wbuffer, n)`

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K85s95k.png работает, добавил параметр /U, благодарю Вас за помощь